# PDO not binding variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

The code below is returning an empty array. When the SQL query is run it returns over 40 rows. Been stuck on this one for over an hour now and staritng to pull my hair out.

One thing I have tried is manually just concatenate the get variables on and then the query **is** successful. Based on that I think the problem is to do with the binding.

```
$_GET['ne'] = '53.23514382039281 -1.4177794752807813';
$_GET['sw'] = '53.23265539538397 -1.4263625441284375';

<?php
ini_set("display_errors",1);
require_once('../../includes/database.php');

try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT X(Coordinates) AS `latitude`, Y(Coordinates) AS `longitude`
                            FROM stop
                            WHERE MBRContains(
                                GeomFromText( 'LINESTRING(:ne,:sw)' ),
                                Coordinates)");

    $stmt->bindParam('ne', $_GET['ne'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
    $stmt->bindParam('sw', $_GET['sw'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);

    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

echo json_encode($results);

?>
```

Comment: Did you try the same query on MySQL ? Did it return results ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Yes, the query works perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot bind parameters which are in quoted string 'LINESTRING(:ne,:sw)'.
If you insist to use binding then try to do this.

```
GeomFromText( concat('LINESTRING(',:ne,',',:sw,')') )
```

BTW you should have been getting this error.

Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

add this line

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

after

```
ini_set("display_errors",1);
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I only insist on using binding as it's the safest way to go about selecting data using PDO.

Answer (score 3):

```
$stmt->bindParam(':ne', $_GET['ne'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
$stmt->bindParam(':sw', $_GET['sw'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
```

You have to execute the statement to get results

$stmt->execute(); See more info [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Comment: Still returning an empty array :{

Comment: Parameter identifier. For a prepared statement using named placeholders, this will be a parameter name of the form :name

Comment: It is optional. Not Mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $stmt->execute() // missing
?>
```

Comment: Wow! It was, too. But sadly still returning an empty array

Comment: @jskidd3 are you storing latitude and longtitude as string ? in sql

Comment: No, they're geospatial points which is why I use the X and Y functions when selecting them. I know there's nothing wrong with the query though because it executes and returns results

Comment: @jskidd3 latitude and longtitude are INT datatype in mysql ?